# Access specific key values on each array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to access/extract specific key values of "serviceCode" the array, how could i do that.

```js
    var x = {


    "0": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_ground\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"28.66\",\"baseAmount\":\"20.19\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge Ground\",\"amount\":\"3.28\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Ground\",\"amount\":\"2.01\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"8\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
        "1": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_second_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"69.72\",\"baseAmount\":\"54.94\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"9.55\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"208\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
        "2": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_next_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"76.62\",\"baseAmount\":\"60.85\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"10.54\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"108\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}"
    };

const me = Object.create(x);

var arr = [];
$.each( me, function( index, value){
    arr.push(value);
    
});

console.log(arr.carrierCode);
```

It always return undefined

Comment: several issues ... 1. each value in `x` is a string, 2. the result is an array, arrays don't have a `carrierCode` property

Comment: solution for 1. is `arr.push(JSON.parse(value));` ... solution for 2. is, learn what arrays are

Answer (score 2):

The values in your array are JSON strings and must be first decoded to objects. Then you can retrieve the `serviceCode` values from them:

```js
var x = {


    "0": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_ground\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"28.66\",\"baseAmount\":\"20.19\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge Ground\",\"amount\":\"3.28\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Ground\",\"amount\":\"2.01\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"8\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
        "1": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_second_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"69.72\",\"baseAmount\":\"54.94\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"9.55\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"208\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
        "2": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_next_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"76.62\",\"baseAmount\":\"60.85\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"10.54\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"108\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}"
    };

const me = Object.create(x);

var arr = [];
$.each( me, function( index, value){
    let obj = JSON.parse(value); // Decode JSON into an object
    arr.push(obj.serviceCode); // Retrieve the value from the object        
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below javascript code will work without jQuery

```js
function getServiceCodes(input) {
  const serviceCodes = [];
  for (const key in input) {
    const option = JSON.parse(input[key]);
    serviceCodes.push(option.serviceCode);
  }
  return serviceCodes;
}

const input = {
  "0": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_ground\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"28.66\",\"baseAmount\":\"20.19\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge Ground\",\"amount\":\"3.28\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Ground\",\"amount\":\"2.01\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"8\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "1": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_second_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"69.72\",\"baseAmount\":\"54.94\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"9.55\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"208\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "2": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_next_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"76.62\",\"baseAmount\":\"60.85\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"10.54\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"108\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}"
};

const output = getServiceCodes(input);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery anymore to manipulate data, keep it for DOM.

Just map the object values with parsing them with `JSON.parse`.
If the JSON is returned from the backend, I would ask the backender to provide it parsed.

If you need your data later I would suggest to mutate it into an array and parse it for later use including your case.

Btw stop using `var` - it's legacy and creates many subtle bugs.

```js
let x = {
  "0": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_ground\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"28.66\",\"baseAmount\":\"20.19\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge Ground\",\"amount\":\"3.28\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Ground\",\"amount\":\"2.01\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"8\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "1": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_second_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"69.72\",\"baseAmount\":\"54.94\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"9.55\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"208\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "2": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_next_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"76.62\",\"baseAmount\":\"60.85\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"10.54\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"108\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}"
};

x = Object.values(x).map(JSON.parse);

const result = x.map(e => e.serviceCode);

console.log(result);
```

But if you need the `serviceCode` property only:

```js
const input = {
  "0": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_ground\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"28.66\",\"baseAmount\":\"20.19\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge Ground\",\"amount\":\"3.28\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Ground\",\"amount\":\"2.01\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"8\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "1": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_second_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"69.72\",\"baseAmount\":\"54.94\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"9.55\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"208\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "2": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_next_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"76.62\",\"baseAmount\":\"60.85\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"10.54\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"108\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}"
};

const result = Object.values(input).map(e => JSON.parse(e).serviceCode);

console.log(result);
```

Another option is parse with a regex, it's faster since you don't need to parse the whole JSON (if you don't need the rest of data later)

```js
const input = {
  "0": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_ground\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"28.66\",\"baseAmount\":\"20.19\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge Ground\",\"amount\":\"3.28\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Ground\",\"amount\":\"2.01\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"8\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "1": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_second_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"69.72\",\"baseAmount\":\"54.94\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"9.55\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"208\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "2": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_next_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"76.62\",\"baseAmount\":\"60.85\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"10.54\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"108\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}"
};

const result = Object.values(input).map(e => e.match(/(?<=serviceCode":")[^"]+/)[0]);

console.log(result);
```

```
` Chrome/120
----------------------------------------------------------------------
regex - Alexander          1.00x  |  x1000000  465  467  490  497  507
JSON.parse - Alexander     5.05x  |   x100000  235  239  245  246  252
jQuery - hotmarycorleone   5.55x  |   x100000  258  267  269  270  273
----------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const input = {
  "0": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_ground\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"28.66\",\"baseAmount\":\"20.19\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge Ground\",\"amount\":\"3.28\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Ground\",\"amount\":\"2.01\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"8\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "1": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_second_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"69.72\",\"baseAmount\":\"54.94\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"9.55\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"208\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}",
  "2": "{\"carrierCode\":\"ups\",\"serviceCode\":\"ups_next_day_air\",\"packageTypeCode\":\"ups_custom_package\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"totalAmount\":\"76.62\",\"baseAmount\":\"60.85\",\"surcharges\":[{\"description\":\"Fuel Surcharge - Domestic Air\",\"amount\":\"10.54\"},{\"description\":\"Residential Express\",\"amount\":\"2.05\"},{\"description\":\"Delivery Confirmation Signature\",\"amount\":\"3.18\"}],\"zone\":\"108\",\"quotedWeight\":\"25\",\"quotedWeightType\":\"Actual\"}"
};

// @benchmark jQuery - hotmarycorleone
var arr = [];
$.each( input, function( index, value){
    let obj = JSON.parse(value); // Decode JSON into an object
    arr.push(obj.serviceCode); // Retrieve the value from the object        
});
arr;


// @benchmark JSON.parse - Alexander
Object.values(input).map(e => JSON.parse(e).serviceCode);

// @benchmark regex - Alexander
Object.values(input).map(e => e.match(/(?<=serviceCode":")[^"]+/)[0]);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Best detailed answer so far. Thank you so much Alexander

Comment: @hotmarycorleone if it solves your problem you could accept it (the gray checkbox), thanks. that's how stackoverflow works